# php str_replace умлаут

Tags: php, строки, str-replace

Как сделать на php замену умлаута в строке?
Обычные символы функция str_replace меняет, а вот умлауты нет.

Делал так:
$city = str_replace('ü','u',$city);

Comment: а если меняет?.

Comment: Проверил на строке `$city = 'München'`, всё отлично меняет. Если у вас не меняет — составьте [mcve], который продемонстрирует некорректное поведение

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился изменением кодировки php файла.